# iwlwifi > hardware restart was requested

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I first discovered that issue when running a Unity3D game (Velocidrone). I also encountered it in another Unity3D game (Liftoff), while I decided to monitor dmesg output ; I don't know for if the issue is related to Unity.

In the first game, I also had "memory leak" that filled in my RAM and SWAP in matter of seconds. After getting in touch with the devs they told me that issue is known, while I was the first to report that it made the computer totally crash. They adviced me to get my swap file from 2GB to something bigger. I did it, It's better for the moment. Still, I do experience another issue that I first thought was related, but maybe not.

As soon I launch the game, wether from the Launcher or directly, I cannot authenticate to the server. Looking in my dmesg, I can see I get that each time.

```
[ 4123.886424] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Queue 11 is active on fifo 1 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [202, 244] HW [202, 244] FH TRB=0x0c010b0d9
[ 4123.886511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[ 4123.886871] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 4123.886872] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[ 4123.886873] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.6bf1df06.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
[ 4123.886875] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[ 4123.886875] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00802EF4 | trm_hw_status0
[ 4123.886876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[ 4123.886877] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004882DA | branchlink2
[ 4123.886878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0047932A | interruptlink1
[ 4123.886879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005A16 | interruptlink2
[ 4123.886879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001ACAA | data1
[ 4123.886880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFF000000 | data2
[ 4123.886881] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0000008 | data3
[ 4123.886882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB9816C09 | beacon time
[ 4123.886883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x036F76DA | tsf low
[ 4123.886883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000121 | tsf hi
[ 4123.886884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 4123.886885] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05E6400B | time gp2
[ 4123.886886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[ 4123.886886] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
[ 4123.886887] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6BF1DF06 | uCode version minor
[ 4123.886888] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
[ 4123.886889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89008 | board version
[ 4123.886890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0BCA001C | hcmd
[ 4123.886890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80022002 | isr0
[ 4123.886891] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[ 4123.886892] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08001802 | isr2
[ 4123.886893] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0041FCCD | isr3
[ 4123.886893] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[ 4123.886894] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0004019C | last cmd Id
[ 4123.886895] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001ACAA | wait_event
[ 4123.886896] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000C82B | l2p_control
[ 4123.886897] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002020 | l2p_duration
[ 4123.886897] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 4123.886898] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[ 4123.886899] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 4123.886900] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08081425 | timestamp
[ 4123.886900] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000F8F0 | flow_handler
[ 4123.887046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 4123.887047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 7
[ 4123.887047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[ 4123.887048] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 4123.887049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008885E | umac branchlink2
[ 4123.887050] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC00843E8 | umac interruptlink1
[ 4123.887051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC00843E8 | umac interruptlink2
[ 4123.887051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[ 4123.887052] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC00843E8 | umac data2
[ 4123.887053] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[ 4123.887054] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | umac major
[ 4123.887054] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6BF1DF06 | umac minor
[ 4123.887055] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05E63FFC | frame pointer
[ 4123.887056] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088627C | stack pointer
[ 4123.887057] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0004019C | last host cmd
[ 4123.887057] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[ 4123.887073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[ 4123.887081] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x24B14081 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[ 4123.887090] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[ 4123.887098] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC3BF9305 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 4123.887106] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[ 4123.887115] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x27FC0BAC | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[ 4123.887123] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3B87F9EF | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[ 4123.887131] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x71985682 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[ 4123.887139] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA6D3EBB5 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[ 4123.887148] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 4123.887158] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 4123.887169] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[ 4123.887210] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[ 4123.887219] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired.
[ 4123.887223] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
```

The game's logs show that I go in offline mode because I'm not connected to the internet.
While running `ping 8.8.8.8` in the same time ; I can see that, indeed, I'm disconnected. The issue might repeat (or not) more than 1 in a row before it re-establish internet by itself, but it's unknow why sometimes it only gets 1 try, sometimes 2, sometimes more.

I'm looking forward for your help debugging this. Thanks

---

#### System information

```
 $ inxi -SPARM -GCDN -v1 -xGCRS
System:    Host: msi Kernel: 5.8.0-44-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: GF65 Thin 9SEXR v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-16W1 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends 
           v: E16W1IMS.108 date: 12/04/2019 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-9300H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 38400 
           Speed: 900 MHz min/max: 800/4100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 900 2: 900 3: 900 4: 900 5: 900 6: 900 7: 900 8: 900 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: nvidia v: 460.39 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1360x768~60Hz, 1920x1080~120Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2060/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.39 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-44-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 5000 bus ID: 00:14.3 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 370.10 GiB (77.6%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLQ512HALU-00000 size: 476.94 GiB 
RAID:      Message: No RAID data was found. 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 370.09 GiB (79.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Info:      Processes: 284 Uptime: 8h 41m Memory: 7.62 GiB used: 3.96 GiB (52.0%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David Oh sorry I forgot that. I just added it